# Processes from F: / G: cannot access C:

Tags: windows-10, privileges

I've always tried to be organized with partitions (C for OS, F for Data and G for programs) however I've always had a problem with this pc: every program in G cannot access C if they arent run with administrator privileges (I'm the only user and administrator on this pc). So if a game can't update, it needs to be ran with administrator priviledges, but then anything can touch the game if they arent elevated (recording softare, overlays, mods) etc. I'm on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your C drive has its permissions set too strictly.

Its common that the C drive is set like this, so any change is flagged and requires administrative privileges. Usually Trusted Installer is the owner of all folders, and the Users group has only read permissions.

As such, any change will either fail or give a UAC login dialog.

**This is expected behavior**

You can fix this by doing the following:

Either do this for the entire C drive (not recommended, as it significantly lowers security) or do it for the folders you really need access too. These are usually in your profile, and possibly inside C:\Program Files.

- Rightclick the folder or drive and choose Properties.
- Go to the tab `Security`
- At the bottom, press the button <kbd>Advanced</kbd>
- At the top, it will say Owner: Trusted Installer, followed by a link labelled `Change` with an administrator shield.
- Click the change button, and change this to your own username and press <kbd>OK</kbd>.
- At the bottom, there is a checkbox saying something like:`[ ] Set permissions on all child objects`. Check it, and press ok.
- Close everything, including the previous windows concerning setting access rights by pressing <kbd>OK</kbd>
- Right click the folder again and select properties and head for the security once more.
- This time, at the top, press <kbd>Edit</kbd> and change Users to read and write and hit <kbd>OK</kbd>

Your problem should now be fixed.

Comment: I did that and when I restarted I got the infinitely spinning circles before login. I am now in safe mode and I even restored a restore point one week old but still same problem.